# Is it possible to obtain multi-spectral images with pi zero camera OV5647?

Tags: raspbian, camera, pi-zero, image

I am trying to capture multi-spectral images with a pizero camera V2.0 with Ssensor OV5647. I want to know how is it possible or if there is some commands?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this
http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Raspberry-Pi-Multispectral-Camera/

But looks like you need multiple cameras which only the compute module has.

if you could use two zero's each with a camera, and trigger at the same time it might work.